# How to bridge an existing eth token to bsc smart chain

Tags: ethereum, abi, erc20, binance-smart-chain, bep20

I created an simple Erc 20 with basic mint and burn functions.I want to deploy it to bsc via a bridge.How do i implement a bridge for Eth-Bsc token?